# Generating CSS modules for React components in Bit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bit, css-modules

We started sharing a number of React components in our SPA as Bit.dev components and ran into an issue: can't use our components on Bit's dashboard due to CSS-modules as Bit's build process does not create them. We use Bit 0.0.687. Use "bit start" to launch Bit dashboard or "bit export" to publish the components to a remote scope, then open a remote dashboard. Our components which use: import style from './style.css' and relay on a CSS module get undefined "style" under Bit. May someone tell, please, if there is a way to alter Bit's build process to generate CSS modules? In our Application's Webpack build we use:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      include: /src/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('style-loader', {
            paths: [require.resolve('webpack-config-single-spa')],
          }),
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve('css-loader', {
            paths: [require.resolve('webpack-config-single-spa')],
          }),
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: true,
            modules: {
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
            },
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  ]}
```

and Webpack 5.x.

Answer (score 1):

As Bit uses CRA under the hood, renaming CSS files to style.module.css helps. CRA recognizes "module" suffix and compiles these CSS as modules.

Comment: Thanks @Alexf2 . It worked with that of Next JS App